# jQuery Serialize() is not working in Ajax POST

Tags: jquery, json, post, serialization

This is my AJAX request

```
$(document).ready(function(){
        $("#register-submit").click(function(){
        var formdata = {hotelname: $('#hotelName').val(), contactType: $('#contactType').val(), contactNumber: $('#contactNumber').val(), addrOne: $('#addrLineOne').val(), addrTwo: $('#addrLineTwo').val(),cityName: $('#cityName').val(), stateName: $('#stateName').val(),localityName: $('#localityName').val(), pincode: $('#pincode').val(), managerName: $('#mngrName').val(), managerEmail: $('#mngrEmail').val(), managerPhone: $('#mngrPhone').val()}
        jQuery.ajax({
                url: "../api/v1/admin/ch_partialBusinessRegister.php",
                data: JSON.stringify(formdata),
                type: "POST",
                async: false,
                success: function(res) {
                    var result = res.Result;
                    if(result.success === true)
                        {
                            alert("Random Password is Generated : "+res.Result.password);
                            window.location.reload();
                        }
                        else
                            alert("Registration Failed. "+res.Result.msg);
                }
            });

    });
});
```

In my ch_partialBusinessRegister.php

```
$inputJson = file_get_contents('php://input');
$post_vars = json_decode($inputJson, true);
$businessName = $post_vars['hotelname'];
$address1 = $post_vars['addrOne'];
$address2 = $post_vars['addrTwo'];
$locality = $post_vars['localityName'];
$city = $post_vars['cityName'];
$state = $post_vars['stateName'];
$zip = $post_vars['pincode'];
$mName = $post_vars['managerName'];
$mEmail = $post_vars['managerEmail'];
$mPhone = $post_vars['managerPhone'];
```

Am able to get the data and pass it in the POST parameters successfully. But when I change the formdata as

```
$(document).ready(function(){
            $("#register-submit").click(function(){
            var formdata = $('form').serializeArray();
            jQuery.ajax({
                    url: "../api/v1/admin/ch_partialBusinessRegister.php",
                    data: JSON.stringify(formdata),
                    type: "POST",
                    async: false,
                    success: function(res) {
                        var result = res.Result;
                        if(result.success === true)
                            {
                                alert("Random Password is Generated : "+res.Result.password);
                                window.location.reload();
                            }
                            else
                                alert("Registration Failed. "+res.Result.msg);
                    }
                });

        });
    });
```

and then JSON.stringify it, it is sending the variables through POST parameters like this

```
[{"name":"hotelName","value":"test"},{"name":"contactType","value":"LandLine"},{"name":"contactNumber[]","value":""},{"name":"AddrOne","value":"test"},{"name":"addrTwo","value":"test"},{"name":"pincode","value":"test"},{"name":"mngrName","value":"test"},{"name":"mngrEmail","value":"test"},{"name":"mngrPhone","value":"test"}]
```

But in PHP it is not reading the values.

Same way if I use

```
var mydata = $('form').serialize();
 data: JSON.stringify(mydata)
```

It Posts this data, but not read by PHP

```
"hotelName=&contactType=LandLine&contactNumber%5B%5D=&AddrOne=&addrTwo=&pincode=&mngrName=test&mngrEmail=test&mngrPhone=test"
```

Comment: `$('form').serialize();` ???

Comment: Yes, I am just serializing the HTML form through jQuery

Comment: But here you are using `serializeArray()` so why not instead use `serialize()` and use relevant name attribute for each input?

Comment: @A.Wolff updated question with serialize() and its POST data. Serialize and serializeArray both are not working for me

Comment: `hotelName` != `hotelname` start to fix it and the same for all your attributes `name`

Comment: I did not notice the name fields in html. Its corrected now. But still same issue.

Comment: Getting this error in php
Warning: Illegal string offset 'hotelName'

Answer (score 1):

you can just add this

```
$(document).ready(function(){
        $("#register-submit").click(function(){
           jQuery.ajax({
           url: "../api/v1/admin/ch_partialBusinessRegister.php",
           type: 'post',
          data: {'inputJson': $('form').serialize()},
          dataType: 'json',
          success: function(res) {
                    var result = res.Result;
                    if(result.success === true)
                        {
                            alert("Random Password is Generated "+res.Result.password);
                            window.location.reload();
                        }
                        else
                            alert("Registration Failed. "+res.Result.msg);
                }
            });

    });
});
```

and in your php file you can just decode the array by typing

```
$inputJson=$_POST['inputJson'];
$post_vars = json_decode($inputJson, true);
```

and if you want to get the value of form tags

```
you can simply write

$tagValue=$post_vars['tagName']; // tag name inside the form which is sent using ajax
```

Comment: Even if I directly use $_POST to get the value from form tags, It says Undefined Index in PHP. Its passing the Post values, but PHP is not reading it.

Comment: sorry , i have made a mistake , there is no post like this            $tagValue=$_POST['tagName'];  instead you should write  $tagValue=$post_vars['tagName'];   i will edit the code right now

Answer (score 0):

just pass your 'myData' object as it is. don't stringify it.

Comment: In that case how to parse it in PHP? I have did a json_decode in php too

Comment: I don't know PHP, but jquery takes this object, and send it as a [key=value] pairs to the server, so my guess is that you should handle it as you would usually read request's parameters in PHP... nothing special here...